# contar quantidade de registros nos últimos meses

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Eu tenho 3 tabelas aeronave, ocorrencia e aeronave_ocorrencia, preciso saber se a mesma aeronave esteve presente em qualquer ocorrencia nos ultimos 2 meses da data_utc para trás, e quantas aeronaves estavam presentes.

Informações das tabelas:
aeronave (id_aeronave, matricula);
ocorrencia (id_ocorrencia, data_utc);
aeronave_ocorrencia(id_aeronave_ocorrencia, id_aeronave, id_ocorrencia)

Estou perdido nessa query, não sei para onde ir HELP:

```
SELECT
  a.matricula,
  count(a.matricula)
FROM
  aeronave a
  JOIN aeronave_ocorrencia ao ON a.id_aeronave = ao.id_aeronave
  JOIN ocorrencia o ON ao.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia
WHERE
  o.data_utc > ADD_MONTHS(o.data_utc , -2 )
GROUP BY 
  a.matricula
```

Comment: Coloque como condição `o.data_utc > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE , -2 )`.

Comment: ou o.data_utc >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE , -2 ),'MM') levando em conta o inicio do mês , o que se quer dizer com "ultimos 2 meses"

Comment: "últimos 2 meses" quer dizer os último 2 meses pegando como referência a data_utc da ocorrência.

Comment: minha dúvida seria , data de hoje 14/8 , seria  de 14/7 a 14/8 , de 1/7 a 14/8 ,... eu entendo como de 1/7 a 14/8

Comment: Se data_utc = 14/08, então seria de 14/06 à 14/08 e assim por diante....Vide que data_utc são várias datas distintas, pode ser 12/08, 03/03...

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT
  a.matricula
FROM
  aeronave a
JOIN 
  aeronave_ocorrencia ao ON a.id_aeronave = ao.id_aeronave
JOIN
  ocorrencia o ON ao.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia
WHERE
  o.data_utc > ADD_MONTHS(CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE), -2)
GROUP BY 
  a.matricula
```

Veja o fiddle [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87d33abc2be506a81a7ae3dae20cb72c).